# Convert Word8Vector.vector to Word8VectorSlice.slice

Tags: type-conversion, sml, smlnj

How can I convert `buf` to `Word8VectorSlice.slice` in sml/nj? For example,

```
val msg = "hello\n";
val buf = Byte.stringToBytes msg; (* how to convert to Word8VectorSlice.slice ?*)
```

Comment: Does `Word8VectorSlice.slice (buf, <<start index>>, SOME <<end index>>)` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Word8VectorSlice.full buf;
```

Docs: http://sml-family.org/Basis/mono-vector-slice.html#SIG:MONO_VECTOR_SLICE.full:VAL